# Where is mapping done for xmlns to the classes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It is said that when xmlns is specified with the uri http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation, it brings in the definition or voaculbalry of classes from presentationframework dll.

I am curious, where is the mapping for the done ? (this question is not of practical significance, i am just curious and trying to understand wpf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx)

You can see a giant list of these attributes in the Object Browser in the node for `PresentationFramework.dll`:

```
[System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Media.Animation"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute(8),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Input"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsPrefixAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "metro"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsCompatibleWithAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06/resourcedictionary-key", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"),
System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute(2),
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(false),
System.CLSCompliantAttribute(true),
System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute,
System.Security.SecurityRulesAttribute(1409286401),
System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("PresentationFramework.dll"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("PresentationFramework.dll"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyDefaultAliasAttribute("PresentationFramework.dll"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Microsoft Corporation"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("Microsoft® .NET Framework"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved."),
System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("4.0.30319.1"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("4.0.30319.1"),
System.Resources.SatelliteContractVersionAttribute("4.0.0.0"),
System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US"),
System.Reflection.AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(true),
System.Reflection.AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("f:\dd\wpf\src\windows.snk"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute,
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06/documentstructure", "System.Windows.Documents.DocumentStructures"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("PresentationFramework.Royale, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("PresentationFramework.Luna, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("PresentationFramework.Aero, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("PresentationFramework.Classic, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("System.Windows.Presentation, PublicKey=00000000000000000400000000000000"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute("mscorlib,", 1),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute("System,", 1),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute("WindowsBase,", 1),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute("PresentationCore,", 1),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute("System.Xaml,", 2),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute("System.Core,", 2),
System.Windows.ThemeInfoAttribute(2, 0),
System.Security.SecurityCriticalAttribute,
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Documents"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shapes"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shell"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Navigation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Data"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media.Animation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Input"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsPrefixAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "av"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Documents"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shapes"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shell"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Navigation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Data"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media.Animation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Input"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsPrefixAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "wpf"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Documents"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shapes"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Shell"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Navigation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Data"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Media.Animation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Input"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsPrefixAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation", "wpf"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml", "System.Windows.Markup"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsPrefixAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml", "x"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Controls"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Documents"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Shapes"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Navigation"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Data"),
System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows"),
System.Runtime.AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute("1.0.21-0"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ReferenceAssemblyAttribute]
```

Comment: thanks for the information. when i double click on presentationframework node from my solution, i get only a tree of the classes and methods of presentationframework. i cannot see the above information even though i tried at a lot of nodes in the object browser. i am using visual c# 2008 express

Comment: Select the assembly and look in the lower right pane (and scroll down)

Comment: I only find this inforation in the lower right pane when i click on presentaiotnframework node in object browser: "Assembly PresentationFramework
    C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll"

Comment: @paseena, i had this same problem. It seems that the object browser does not display assembly attributes of the selected assembly under "My solution" scope. Go to the top of the object browser and change the scope to your targeted .net framework version. Then click on the assembly interested. You will see all the attributes displayed in the lower right panel.